# React 18 useId cannot be in key

Tags: reactjs, react-18

The error: React Hook "useId" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function.
So, question, where we can use useId()?
I also got the same id for my mapped divs with the code:

```
// @ts-ignore
import React, {useRef, useState, useId} from 'react';

interface InputLocationProps {
    cleanAddress(): void
}

export const InputLocation: React.FC<InputLocationProps> = ({cleanAddress}) => {
    const id = useId()
    const ref = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
    const [text, setText] = useState<string>('');
    const [textArray, setTextArray] = useState<string[]>(['more']);
    const changeHandler = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        setText(event.target.value)
    }
    const putTextInArray = (puttingText: string) => {
        setTextArray(prevState => [ ...prevState, puttingText])
    }
    const keyPressHandler = (event: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {

        if (event.key === 'Enter') {
            event.preventDefault();
            putTextInArray(text)
            console.log(ref.current!.value)
            ref.current!.value = '';
            setText('');
            cleanAddress();
        }
    }
    return (
        <form>
            <label htmlFor="count">{text}</label>
            <input ref={ref} onChange={changeHandler} onKeyPress={keyPressHandler} type="text" id="count"/>
            {textArray.map(textArrayItem => {
                return <div key={useId()}>{textArrayItem}</div>
            })}
        </form>
    );
};
```

Comment: can you share more code? my assumption is you have a class component not a function component

Comment: I work with funciton component. Wait a sec.

Comment: React in its twitter said: We don’t recommend using it for keys — keys should be determined from your data. The primary use case for useId() has to do with accessibility APIs.

Comment: @S.Marx, what is accessibility APIs? Maybe some example?

Comment: yeah you cant use the useId hook in the key={} why not use the const key={id}

Comment: @FerelUltra they recommend reading the original feature request: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/5867

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According [documentation](https://react.dev/reference/react/useId#generating-ids-for-several-related-elements):

```
const Component = () => {
  // outside callback
  const id = useId();

  return array.map((item, index) => <div key={`${id}-${index}`}>some content</div>
}
```

Regarding comments of junior perfectionists and react doc [pitfall](https://react.dev/reference/react/useId#usage) about useId:

1. Use callback outside as mentioned in example - not inside (`key={userId()}`) and you don't have any side effects for **simple list logic** (view without edit).
2. For cases with editing data - it's best practice to use server response ids.

Comment: is this a good practice ?

Comment: There is no such thing in the documentation. In fact the documentation [explicitly prohibits](https://react.dev/reference/react/useId#usage) using useId() for generating keys for a list.

Comment: I agree with @Haris, this should not be the accepted answer.

Comment: This is not a good practice. One should not use useID or the combination with index. 
The purpose of useId hook is generating ids for accessibility and having same ids between client and server render.
Please check the docs here - https://react.dev/reference/react/useId

Answer (score 4):

**useId** is **NOT** for generating keys in a list. Keys should be generated from your data.

check [**documentation**](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useid)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The problem is if you have to generate ids for two lists of identical data that appear twice on the same page - in which case the accepted answer is the right solution

Answer (score 0):

useId hook is used for generating unique ID, since it generates ID on every render, it can't be used inside any rendering functions.

```
const Component = () => {
 const id = useId();
 return array.map(i => <p key={id}>i</p>)
 }
```